# How to use zip function transpose in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, zip

The zip function in swift

```
   let words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
   let numbers = 1...4

   for (word, number) in zip(words, numbers) {
      print("\(word): \(number)")
   }

  // Prints "one: 1"
  // Prints "two: 2
  // Prints "three: 3"
  // Prints "four: 4"
```

but if I want transpose  `[(one,1),(two,2),(three,3),(four,4)]` to `["one", "two", "three", "four"]` and `[1,2,3,4]`.

How to do this in swift, are there similar methods for direct conversion in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `map` twice to "unzip" the arrays:

```
let arr = [("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3), ("four", 4)]

let arr1 = arr.map { $0.0 }
let arr2 = arr.map { $0.1 }

print(arr1) // ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
print(arr2) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

You can also use `reduce` to do this in one shot:

```
let (arr3, arr4) = arr.reduce(([], [])) { ($0.0 + [$1.0], $0.1 + [$1.1]) }

print(arr3) // ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
print(arr4) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `but it requires you to know the types of the arrays` — No, it doesn't. `arr.reduce(([], [])) { ($0.0 + [$1.0], $0.1 + [$1.1]) }` works just fine.

Comment: Thanks @user28434.  Swift still amazes me sometimes with its ability to infer types and puzzles me at other times at its inability to infer types.